# How can I synchronize mutliple threads using mutex?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm a learner, trying to build knowledge of multithreaded programming.  In particular, I want to understand how to use mutexes with pthreads.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t x,y;
static int p=0;
void print(char *x)
{
        p++;
        printf("%d ------ %s\n",p,x);
}
void * thread_1(char *m)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
                print(m);
        }
}

void * thread_2(char *m)
{
        int i;
        sleep(1);
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
                print(m);
        }

}
int main()
{

        pthread_t t1;
        pthread_t t2;
        pthread_mutex_init(&y,NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&x,NULL);
        pthread_create(&t1,NULL,thread_1,"thread_1");
        pthread_create(&t2,NULL,thread_2,"thread_2");

        while(1);
}
```

I created two threads and now I'm trying to synchronize them.  Where should I lock and unlock using two mutexes?

I want to output like this:

```
1 ----- thread_1  
2 ----- thread_2   
3 ----- thread_1   
4 ----- thread_2   
5 ----- thread_1   
6 ----- thread_2    
7 ----- thread_1   
8 ----- thread_2     
9 ----- thread_1        
10 ----- thread_2   
11 ----- thread_1   
12 ----- thread_2   
13 ----- thread_1   
14 ----- thread_2   
15 ----- thread_1   
16 ----- thread_2   
17 ----- thread_1   
18 ----- thread_2   
19 ----- thread_1   
20 ----- thread_2
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to make the function `print` re-entrant by surrounding every access to `p` by the mutex. Ideally keep the code between lock and unlock brief: `lock(); p++; int p_copy = p; unlock(); printf(..., p_copy);`

Comment: @DevangKubavat for clarifying please edit your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Why is it that the first thing everyone tries to do with threads is to completely defeat the entire point of having threads in the first place? If you want things to occur in a precise, sequential order, why use threads?!

Comment: i want to learn about mutex that's why @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @DevangKubavat Then use mutexes for something people typically use mutexes for (providing mutual exclusion) and save doing things that have no relationship to typical uses later. The whole point of using a mutex is to maintain correctness while permitting freedom in the order in which thread accesses can occur. If you don't need such freedom, you don't need a mutex.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but, but .... threads are COOL! Thats what the teacher told them! They can do magic!

Comment: Yes, this requirement would be a misuse of the mutex synchro mechanism.  Use a pair of semaphores instead, swapping a 'print permit' between the thread functions, as almost suggested by l3x below, (note that s/he made an initialization error, but that is the correct mechanism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can certainly be done using mutexes, but a pair of semaphores is more appropriate for this task. Use two semaphores, each associated with a thread which posts to the other thread to inform its turn.
Note that the thread function takes a `void*`, not `char*`.

```
void * thread_1(void *m)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
                sem_wait(&sem2);
                print(m);
                sem_post(&sem1);
        }
}

void * thread_2(void *m)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
                sem_wait(&sem1);
                print(m);
                sem_post(&sem2);
        }
}

int main(void) {
 ...
 sem_init(&sem1, 0, 0);
 sem_init(&sem2, 0, 1);
 ...
}
```

The `sleep()` call is unnecessary. You don't need to have an infinite loop in main() thread either. If you want the threads to complete then use `pthread_join()`. Or simply call `pthread_exit(0);` instead of `while(1);`.

---

Use a mutex and conditional variable pair which alternates between threads using another variable for informing the turn. Essentially the same logic as above but a bit "heavy" for this task. I am not sure why you "must" use mutex :(

```
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int turn = 0;

void print(char *x)
{
        p++;
        printf("%d ------ %s\n",p,x);
}
void * thread_1(void *m)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           while (turn != 0)
              pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
           print(m);
           turn = 1;
           pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
}

void * thread_2(void *m)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while (turn != 1)
               pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            print(m);
            turn = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
}
```

Comment: but i want to learn about mutex... thats why i used here... @l3x

Comment: @DevangKubavat Mutual exclusion would not guarantee the outcome you want as the unlocking thread could be the one to immediately acquire the lock again after it has been released. That's why semaphores are the right tool for your use case. Learning WHEN to use something is also very important.

Comment: @DevangKubavat Learning about mutexes is fine. But you also need to understand whether the task at hand really needs a mutex. I updated with an answer that uses mutex but it's really unnecessary.

Comment: @I3x ... can u give example at where i can use 2 mutexs to synchronize the two thread.... because i am new in synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @DevangKubavat Perhaps, read a textbook on pthreads and when to use what construct. Search the internet. You can find plenty of examples using mutexes.

Comment: okay thanks..... @l3x

Comment: Note:  your semaphore solution, as posted, will not work:(  You initialized both semaphores with 1, resulting in incorrect behaviour.  You only need ONE 'print token' in the system, eg: sem_init(&sem2, 0, 1); sem_init(&sem2, 0, 0);

Comment: @MartinJames It's undefined behaviour to initialize the same semaphore twice (I was actually initializing sem2 twice - copy-paste error). Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: @l3x what?  I got it wrong too?  [facepalm] :)